# unit test node.js mongoose mocha chai sinon

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mongoose, mocha.js, sinon

I'm new to unit testing. My Web API project is MVC base on node-express-mongoose.

I have a `conroller.js` as following:

```
const getComments = async (req, res) => {
  let query = {};

  try {
    query = req.query.filter ? { email: new RegExp(`.*${req.query.filter}.*`, 'i') } : query;
    const comments = await util.getComments(query);
    return res.json(comments);
  } catch (err) {
    return res.status(500).send(`Internal server error: ${err}`);
  }
};
```

The controller use `util.js` function(s) which implements all database operations:

```
const comments = require('../models/comments');

exports.getComments = (query) => {
      try {
        return comments.find(query).sort({ createdAt: -1 });
      } catch (err) {
        throw err;
      }
};
```

How do I create unit test using mocha & chai? Do I have to create fake mock using sinon etc?

Comment: You cannot unit test database call, You can only test getComments method that it has query object. Cuz You'll have to mock database model response. You've to use mongo-in-memory (https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongo-in-memory) and simulate mongodb.

Comment: It's not possible to insert fake data using sinon?

Comment: I mean it's possible but it's not unit test. In fact You're testing comments model not getComments method itself. that means You don't test Your own code, You test mongoose model that is already tested by mongoose contributors.

Comment: I've made update on example with virtual in memory database server that will be very helpful in Your question. But make sure that mocked data is same as in Your model

Comment: Tnx. I didn't understand why it's not "unit test" to test your own method? Does unit test not include db operations? How you should do unit test if you got alike method in the code?

Comment: Your code just calls another code, even try...catch is useless in such method. It's same as You directly call that method without getComments. When I do write tests I use Repository and Service pattern. It's a bit difficult to understand.
But ok, let's not complicate Your understanding of code and use that example in my answer below. I does what You want.

Comment: I updated my question. I understand your point. To be clear, I'm working in MVC using Generic Repository Pattern. Therefore, all database operations whatever they are separated to the model layer which consume "pure" input after validation etc.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171852/discussion-between-wizard-and-num8er).

Answer (score 2):

Wait wait....

The question states that we are talking about "unit tests", so unit test are those ones where we assess the correct beahviour of the function/class/whatever WE have developed. Just this and anything else. Now, too bad I'm not a mongoDB dev, neither a mongo-memory-server contributor, so I don't really need to take into account these softwares in my tests. This is the reason test doubles (stubs/mocks/spies) were born and we, as good software engineers, should make a wise use of them

so, this is my unit test:

```js
const {expect} = require("chai")
const sinon = require("sinon")

const uut = require("./users.service")

const UserModel = require("./user.model")

it("given correct userId should retrieve users full name" , async () => {

    //given
    const fixture = {
        _id : "fakeuser",
        name: "Fake",
        surname: "User"
    }

    let stub = sinon.stub(UserModel , "findById").returns(fixture)

    //when
    let result = await uut.getUserFullnameById(fixture._id)

    //then
    expect(result).to.eq("Fake User")
    stub.restore()

})
```

This test tell me that getUserFullnameById function behaves correctly,

```js
const User = require("./user.model")

module.exports.getUserFullnameById = async function (userId) {

    let user = await User.findById(userId)
    
    return `${user.name} ${user.surname}`
}
```

I isolate my logic from mongoose because I don't need to know if mongoose works and I'm able to connect to a underlying mongodb instance. So someone could point that my test passes even if there is no "findById" API in mongoose library, so that's why I rely on integration tests as well

```js
describe("integration test" , () => {

    const mongoose = require("mongoose")
    

    before(()=> {
        mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/db" , { useNewUrlParser: true , useUnifiedTopology: true})
        mongoose.Promise = global.Promise
    })

    beforeEach(async ()=> {
        await mongoose.connection.dropDatabase()
    })

    it("given correct userId should retrieve users full name" , async () => {

        let fixture  = new UserModel({name : "Fake" , surname : "User"})

        await fixture.save()

        let result = await uut.getUserFullnameById(fixture._id)

        expect(result).to.eq("Fake User")


    })
})
```

the integration test does the same thing as before, but does it whithin a context. if i mess around with my method under test, I could break the integration test and i will know that I am misusing mongoose or mongodb connection, or I can break both, so I know that I am likely just disrespecting my business rules. Another advantage: integration tests are slow and brittle, but I can provide quality code even providing less of them and adding more isolated unit tests

Now you have two more cases: first name not present and last name not present: how do you test and extend your code?

Answer (score 1):

If I want to write test on method that cannot be avoided without mocking of db I use [mongodb-memory-server](https://github.com/nodkz/mongodb-memory-server) that acts as database and simulates mongodb behaviour.

```
const Comment = require('../models/comments');

const mockedComments = [ // modify example data depending on Your model
  {userId: "1", body: "Mocked comment of user 1", createdAt: Date.now() },
  {userId: "2", body: "Mocked comment of user 2", createdAt: Date.now() },
];

const getComments = require('../path/to/getComments');


const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const MongodbMemoryServer = require('mongodb-memory-server');

let mongoServer;
const opts = { useMongoClient: true }; 

before((done) => {
  mongoServer = new MongodbMemoryServer();

  mongoServer.getConnectionString()
    .then((mongoUri) => {
      return mongoose.connect(mongoUri, opts, (err) => {
        if (err) done(err);
      });
    })
    .then(() => {
     // preparing in memory database contents 
     Promise.all([
       Comment.create(mockedComments[0]),
       Comment.create(mockedComments[1])
     ]).then(() => done());
    });
});

after(() => {
  mongoose.disconnect();
  mongoServer.stop();
});

describe('getComments', () => {

  it('successfully returns comments', async () => {
    const result = await getComments({});
    expect(result.length).to.equal(mockedComments.length);
  });

  it('successfully returns comments of user', async () => {
    const result = await getComments({userId: 1});
    expect(result[0].userId).to.equal(1);
  });
});
```